# R (rvest) Web Scraping Multiple Pages

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping, rvest

I am looking to **scrape** the results from the Philly DA Democratic Primary race. I want to **scrape** the ward-division results from the website. I need the ward-division number (e.g. 01-01), the name of the candidate (e.g. LARRY KRASNER), and the percent each candidate received. For this website, there are 86 pages of results at the ward-division level:

https://results.philadelphiavotes.com/ResultsSW.aspx?type=CTY&map=CTY#page-1

Using the SelectorGadget tool, the CSS for each are as follows:

```
ward-division numbers = ".precinct-results-orangebox-title h1"
name of candidates= ".precinct-results-databox1 h1"
percent results= "#Datawrapper 16DEM .bar-percent"
```

When I tried to initially **scrape** the website data, I used the following code:

```
#Read in the Data
daresults <- read_html (https://results.philadelphiavotes.com/ResultsSW.aspx type=CTY&map=CTY#page-1) 

#Ward-Division Numbers
warddiv<-daresults %>%
html_nodes(".precinct-results-orangebox-title h1")%>%
html_text()
```

And I received a response of

```
character(0)
```

Any help on cleaning up the code and creating a loop to **scrape** all 86 pages would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data is stored as a JSON file.  From the Network tab, from your browser's developer tools the files are located here:

https://phillyresws.azurewebsites.us/ResultsAjax.svc/GetMapData?type=CTY&category=PREC&raceID=16&osn=16&county=04&party=DEM&LanguageID=1

https://phillyresws.azurewebsites.us/ResultsAjax.svc/GetMapData?type=CTY&category=PREC&raceID=17&osn=17&county=04&party=REP&LanguageID=1

https://phillyresws.azurewebsites.us/ResultsAjax.svc/GetMapData?type=CTY&category=PREC&raceID=18&osn=18&county=04&party=DEM&LanguageID=1

https://phillyresws.azurewebsites.us/ResultsAjax.svc/GetMapData?type=CTY&category=PREC&raceID=19&osn=19&county=04&party=REP&LanguageID=1

Use jsonlite or another package to read the file and parse the file into a data frame.
For example:

```
url<-"https://phillyresws.azurewebsites.us/ResultsAjax.svc/GetMapData?type=CTY&category=PREC&raceID=16&osn=16&county=04&party=DEM&LanguageID=1"
jsonlite::fromJSON(url)
```